# Why are there so many chickens and chicken references in Lego Avengers?

Tags: lego-marvel-avengers

There's an insane amount of chickens and chicken references in Lego  Marvel's Avengers.

Any idea why there are so many chickens?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. It isn't so much a question of game design as it is a question about potential lore in the universe/game.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Based on the answer being accepted, I would dispute that assumption.

Comment: Just reading the comments above I wanted to clarify why I asked the question. I was not so much interested in the game design but more about any ties to the mythos, or linkage between games and the plot of why the chickens are there. Although I can't see any close votes (maybe I don't have the rep to see that). I feel that the question I asked would be considered "Plot and characters in games" which is one of the example question types detailed in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, its just an attempt to make the game funny.  Lego games are known to be silly in this sense.

[In one article](https://theinsightfulpanda.com/2015/10/30/lego-marvels-avengers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-this-avengers-celebration/) they mention the Hulk has a chicken to help keep him angry. That was under the section titled "Returning Humor – More Laughs & Inside Jokes Than ever Before."

There is also a part (and this may be a spolier) where:

> You use mind control on chickens that are harassing Stan Lee in [Barton's Farm](http://www.ign.com/wikis/lego-marvel-avengers/Barton's_Farm) to get the 8th gold brick.

Taking in to account the above, the chickens are just an attempt to make the game humorous.